# Why am I getting the error: "Error: Render_to_response not defined"; Django

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django, and I found a very basic example online on how to display tables using templates. I followed the code exactly, but for some reason I get the error:

```
Error: Render_to_response not defined
```

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def display(request):
    return render_to_response('template.tmpl', {'obj':models.Book.objects.all()})
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # /table/
    url(r'^$', views.display, name='display'),
]
```

Here is my template.tmpl:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>author</th>
  <th>title</th>
  <th>publication year</th>
</tr>
{% for b in obj %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ b.author }}</td>
  <td>{{ b.title }}</td>
  <td>{{ b.publication_year }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    publication_year = models.IntegerField()
```

I've looked online for some help with this error, but all the problems seem to be much more complicated than the one I'm facing. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are importing `render` but using `render_to_response`

Replace `render_to_response`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def display(request):
    return render(request, 'template.tmpl', {'obj':models.Book.objects.all()})
```

Comment: Wow... That was really simple. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yep, I can do it now. It told me to wait a few minutes. Thanks for the reminder and the answer! :)

Comment: This won't work - apart from the typo (missing comma), `render` takes the request as the first parameter, not the template.

Comment: Great @AndrewQuoc-AnhHo 
wc

Comment: Its probably worth noting that [`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response), as noted in the docs, is likely to be deprecated in the future. cc: @AndrewQuoc-AnhHo